# Jquery Scrolling Div pushes content off bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, sticky

I'm trying to get a div following scrolls down the page. It works pretty well but the div is getting stuck at the bottom of the page when i try to scroll too far:

```
$(function() {
    var $sidebar = $("#sidebar"),
        $bigPics = $("#bigPics"),
        $window = $(window),
        offset = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 20,
        turnoff = 1;
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if (($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) && (documentHeight - 1200 > parseFloat($sidebar.css("marginTop")))) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop();
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how to make it start again when I scroll back up the page? Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$sidebar.css({'position':'absolute','top':0,'right':0});
var extraValue=0,sidebarHeight=$sidebar.height();
$window.scroll(function() {
    $sidebar.stop(true,true).animate({
       top: $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() - sidebarHeight + extraValue
    });
});
```

You can easily achieve this by using css:

```
.sidebar{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
right:0;
}

/* for browser not supporting fixed position as ie6 */
.oldBrowser .sidebar{
position:absolute;
top:expression( documentElement.scrollTop + body.scrollTop + yourExtraValue );
}
```

You need to determine when there is an old browser and add the class ".oldBrowser to the body tag element. You can do it in server side or client side when document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

i have used jquery plugin

https://github.com/garand/sticky

to stop at bottom:

(function($) {

```
var limit_bottom=$('#footer').height(); 
$('.product-box').sticky({topSpacing:0, bottomSpacing:limit_bottom});
```

})(jQuery);